# why i can't initialize variable after declaring it?

Tags: java

```
/*

       public class Saur {
        int a;
        a=10;
        }

   */


    public class Saur {
    int a=10;


    }
```

In Commented code why  am not able to initialize ?
while in another i am able to initialize.
what could be the reason for it?

Comment: This is already answered here, couldn't find the duplicate

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan - Ya.. neither could I. But I distinctly remember that question being asked :)

Comment: Took long enough to find a duplicate that was somewhat suitable and reasonably answered...but yes, this question has been covered before.

Comment: @Makoto : Great, You have found the original :)

Comment: It just dawned on me that *you* answered this question a ways back @AbimaranKugathasan.  Small world, eh? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it here because it is not in a code block (i.e. a method).

If `a = 10;` was in a constructor or other method it would be no trouble.

Answer (score 1):

That's just the Java syntax.

Outside of methods or other code blocks, you cannot have statements.

You can only have field declarations.

```
 int a=10;  // declares (and initializes a field)

 int a;     // declare a field

 a=10;    // is a statement (like System.out.println()). Not allowed here.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class Saur {
      int a; // declaration
      a=10; // initialization in statement
  }


  public class Saur {
       int a=10; // declaration with initialization
  }
```

You can not write statements out side of code locks (methods and constructors).
Below is the right way.

```
 public class Saur {
      int a; // declaration
      public Saur (){ a=10; // initialization in statement }

  }
```

Comment: int a; // declaration and "initialize to 0" at runtime.

Comment: int a; // declaration and "initialize to 0" at runtime, but it it declaration + initialization

Comment: a=10; // is not the declaration, it is only initialization

Comment: Technically. a=10; will not be initialization. It will be changing the value of a (initialized to 0 ) to 10.